# Assertion Failed: A helper named "_" could not be found

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I tried to install a few addons like ember-light-table and ember-data-tables but their helpers don't work for me in the template. I get this error: `"Assertion Failed: A helper named "light-table" could not be found"`

I tried to clear all cache, tmp, etc:

```
npm cache clear && bower cache clean && rm -rf node_modules bower_components dist tmp && npm i && bower I
```

But still not working for me

Comment: You have restarted the server as well I hope? Any build errors? The add-ons are in your package.json?

Comment: Server was restarted. No build errors and the addons are in the package.json.